# Exiting from a loop exits the function instead

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I've been coding in Inno Setup this afternoon and I read some [Pascal documentation](http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/pascal/lang_ref/ref_state.doc.html#612) which says that `exit` is used to exit a loop. I tried using that in my code and instead it exited the function. For example in this function the message box will never be shown:

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var i: Integer;
begin
    Result := True;

    for i := 0 to 4 do
    begin
        exit
    end;

    MsgBox('test',mbInformation,MB_OK);
end;
```

I did some more googling and Pascal also has the `break` keyword so I used that and it works properly. Is `exit` really supposed to be used to exit the function? I recall reading this afternoon that Pascal does not have the equivalent of a C style return statement.

I really need some good documentation for the version of Pascal that Inno Setup is using. I have read the Inno help pages but they don't cover things like this. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong documentation, your link refers to the [`Sun Workshop Compiler Pascal 4.2`](http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/pascal/lang_ref/preface.doc.html). Inno setup uses as scripting language The [`RemObjects Pascal Script`](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) Which is a  Delphi-like Pascal dialect, the official documentation of the Pascal Sripting used by Inno is located [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptintro), additionally you can check the [`Marco Cantù's
Essential Pascal`](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/English/default.htm).